# Sorting a dictionary by a key which is in timestamp format

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, timestamp

I have a dictionary of this format:

```
   ['This a text','Sat Nov 26 2011', .....],['This is another text','Sat Aug 26 2012',...],.....
```

I would like to sort this dictionary based on the second field i.e, timestamp in the format: Sat Nov 26 2011. I realize a similar question has been asked ([Sort dictionaries based on timestamp in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609124/sort-dictionaries-based-on-timestamp-in-python)) but the timestamp in that question is an integer. Could anyone please let me know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(that is a `list` of `list`s, not a `dict`)

You just need to provide the mapping to turn each element of your list into a `datetime` object, which will sort appropriately.

```
from datetime import datetime
sorted(li, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], '%a %b %d %Y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Having your list of items to sort:

```
lst = [['This a text','Sat Nov 26 2011', .....],['This is another text','Sat Aug 26 2012',...], ...]
```

and functions, which can convert datetime string into datetime data structure (which is already sortable):

```
def datestr2datetime(datestr):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%a %b %d %Y")
```

You can create sorted list:

```
sortedlst = sorted(lst, key = lambda itm: datestr2datetime(itm[1]))
```

The `lambda` function creates a function, which is able converting particular items in your list into some values, which are then sorted and are determining final order of original items in the lst.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `sorted(key=)` syntax from the answer you linked to along with converting the date strings to actual date objects.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = [['more text','Sat Jan 10 2013'],['other text','Sat Aug 14 2014'],['text','Sat Jul 27 2005']]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1],'%a %b %d %Y'))
[['text', 'Sat Jul 27 2005'], ['more text', 'Sat Jan 10 2013'], ['other text', 'Sat Aug 14 2014']]
```

The [formatting rules for strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) will depend on how exactly the string is formatted.

Alternatively, if you want to modify the list in-place, the list.sort() method takes the same key param.

```
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1],'%a %b %d %Y'))
>>> a
[['text', 'Sat Jul 27 2005'], ['more text', 'Sat Jan 10 2013'], ['other text', 'Sat Aug 14 2014']]
```